# Sending data to PHP with AJAX and assigning answer to text box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am writing a very simple web form where i am sending data from a text box to the PHP with jQuery AJAX and want to populate a label in the html page with the response (manipulated in php)

I am working without a form in the HTML page, but instead using multiple objects, since the page should contain 3 steps, and I do not want to use action.

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

**HTML/JS**

```
        function funcGetBatches() {
            CatNum = document.getElementById("CatNumber");
            console.log(CatNum.value);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "./php/conn.php",
                data: CatNum.value,
                datatype: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Succeeded!!!" + CatNum.value);
                    $("#partName").text('__________');
                },
                Error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {}
            });
       }
    var button1 = document.getElementById("getBatches");
    button1.addEventListener("click", funcGetBatches);
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_GET)){
$myCatNum = $_GET['CatNum.value'] + " success!";
  console.log("MyCatNum: " + $myCatNum);
'________________'
}
```

I am logging the process in the php code and indeed see it running

I do believe that i am missing one or two pieces of code, I have marked both places in the code with ____________.

Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: `data: value` is an issue.  If you expect the backend to get the data in the form of a queryString, which `$_GET` would expect, the data needs to be a key value pair  like `data: { catNum: CatNum.value }`.  Then `$_GET['catNum']` should work

Comment: You have PHP and AJAX labels backwards.

Comment: `Error:` should be `error:`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Have you tried logging `data` to console in the `$.ajax({success(data){}})` function?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you do not mix Native JavaScript and jQuery. Consider the following jQuery Script:

```
function funcGetBatches() {
  var CatNum = $("#CatNumber").val();
  console.log(CatNum);

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./php/conn.php",
    data: { catnum: CatNum },
    datatype: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("Succeeded!!!", CatNum, data);
      $("#partName").text(data);
    },
    error: function(x, s, e) {
      console.log(x, s, e);
    }
  });
}
$("#getBatches").click(funcGetBatches);
```

This will post the `CatNum` to the PHP Script and any Text data that is returned will be added to the `#partName` element.

In regards to PHP, this must echo data out.

```
$parts = array(
  "Elbow",
  "Conduit",
  "Nipple",
  "Coupler"
);
if(isset($_GET['catnum'])){
  $cNum = (int)$_GET['catnum'];
  echo $parts[$cNum];
}
```

As you can see, this might be a way to return new data based on the submitted GET request.